# password recovered in weird format

Tags: unicode, characters, hexadecimal

i have been trying for years to recover my old data from very old DS cards " MMC "
recently i found out it is possible to get to mmcstore file that stores the password in plaints text
all went good until i found weird characters in password , i think it may contains invisible characters
any suggestions ?

this is the recovered password :

```
            ؛e   
j o k e r
```

download from dropbox :
file size 1 kb
https://www.dropbox.com/s/27yz43sbx4vh3ft/mmcstore?dl=0

Comment: Seems like Unicode. Post the file online and we can tell mode.

Comment: i updated original post with a direct link , thanks for your interest to answer my question so fast

Comment: This is indeed very simple Unicode and your password seems to be `joker`.

Comment: i already tried joker and didnt work

Comment: There's nothing else that seems useful in the file, except for some binary data.

Comment: File should contain plaint password , seeing additional unicodes or binary data indicates other than regular text in password

Answer (score 0):

Here is the file viewed in the [HxD hexadecimal editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) ("hexeditor"):

[image: Password file in Hex]

Is it possible you used some DOS characters, such as the playing-card symbols?

Have you tried copying and pasting the password into the recovery app?

Comment: The password is indeed 'joker' but with additional spaces making it 'j o k e r'.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas, no, those are *not* spaces, i.e., Chr(32), but 0x00, used when single-byte characters are converted to Unicode, in all likelihood.

Comment: I don't remember if playing-cards symbols are included or not but I doubt it since i created password in very old nokia n70 or older , and i tant be 'j o k e r' since that exeeds max length in one extra character

Comment: would capitalisation be placed in unicode as just capitals?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas, see the ASCII chart: https://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php and for IBM PC DOS, https://www.ascii-codes.com/

Comment: @JohnnyVegas that has nothing to do with Unicode. The first 256 Unicode characters are from ISO-8859-1 which is an exact superset of ASCII, so it contains both lower and uppercase characters

Comment: Thankyou - as you may be able to tell, unicode is not my specialist subject